# How to redirect user back to the app after payment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Flow will be as below:

```
1. User taps on "Pay Now" in the app.
2. An in-app WebView will be opened up and user will be required to make the payment in a third-party payment page. 
3. After payment, user will be redirected to another link.
```

How can we bring the user back to the app after payment ? Shall we use Deeplink or URL Change Listener ?

1. For Deeplink, will user be prompted a popup even if it is an in-app webview ? This is not an ideal behavior that we want.

We would like to have a smooth transition back to the app after Step 3 (for iOS and Android).

We are using React Native as the frontend and Nodejs as the backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've implemented this simple solution some times ago. Using web view, I'm checking url to know if I'm done:

```
checkUrlState = (url) => {
    if (url.includes('specific/part/of/your/url')) {
      // code to hide WebView
    } 
}

<WebView
  ...yourOtherProps
  onNavigationStateChange={state => this.checkUrlState(state.url)}
/>
```

Comment: simple yet effective